# Can't remove encoding returned in $_COOKIE in PHP (on MAMP Server)

Tags: php, cookies, urldecode

I finally got cookies to work only for my output to display like this:

> You last requested an internship opportunity on
>   Wednesday%2C+November+15%2C+2017%2C+3%3A+33+AM.

I have tried using urldecode(),rawurldecode(), setrawcookie(), implode(), and explode(). None of these have had any affect on the output, and I haven't seen other suggestions in similar questions. If anyone has an idea of what might work, I would appreciate the information.

Below I have included some of the code (there's two files involved so I won't post those unless necessary).

Cookie info pulled from top of page

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['LastRequestDate']))
    $LastRequestDate = $_COOKIE['LastRequestDate'];
else
    $LastRequestDate = "";
```

Cookie variable displayed

```
echo "<p>You last requested an internship opportunity on ".$LastRequestDate."</p>";
```

Here's the code that set's the cookie from another page. I have tried removing the urlencode() but nothing changes.

```
setcookie("LastRequestDate", urlencode($DisplayDate), time()+60*60*24*7, "/");
```

Comment: The `setcookie()` call will automatically apply necessary url encoding to the string. You are doubly encoding it - if you removed that `urlencode()` call but saw no change, perhaps you were not modifying the right file? It should not be necessary to call `urldecode()` on a cookie string - PHP does so automatically. But you _should_ call `htmlspecialchars($LastRequstDate)` to escape it for HTML display.

Comment: Try to remove the `urlencode()` from `setcookie()` again, verify you have all the right files for testing, and remove any existing cookies from the browser you're testing against. Aside from the `urlencode()`, your code should function as it is.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, thank you for your response. The below suggestion worked, but I will keep your suggestions in mind in case I have a similar problem in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
<?php
  $DisplayDate = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A") ;
  $base64 = base64_encode($DisplayDate);

  setcookie("LastRequestDate", $base64, time()+60*60*24*7, "/");

  $LastRequestDate = $_COOKIE['LastRequestDate'];
  echo base64_decode($LastRequestDate);
?>
```